I have a question about a RL circuit problem
I need help solving the circuit in the image to find v(t) for t>0
Circuit Description:

The circuit consists of the following elements:

Resistors: 6kΩ, 10kΩ, 8kΩ, 12kΩ, 30kΩ, 18kΩ, and 24kΩ.
Current source: 9mA
Inductor: 10mH


At t = 0 , a switch changes the configuration of the circuit, and I need to find the voltage v(t) across the 6kΩ resistor for  t > 0.

What I’ve Tried:
I understand that the solution might involve solving a differential equation for the inductor current and then using it to calculate v(t). However, I'm struggling with setting up the initial conditions and determining how the inductor behaves immediately after  t = 0.
Question:

How can I set up the equations to find   v(t)  for  t > 0  in this circuit?
What method would be best for solving this type of first-order transient response?

Thank you in advance for any help!


Here are some steps you can follow:
Choose bottom node as GND. Assume that the switch was closed for a long time before it was open at t=0. In steady state when the switch is closed, find current in inductor.At \$t = 0^- \$, the inductor would be a short circuit. You can ignore resistors to the right of the inductor.Current in the inductor doesn't change between \$t= 0^-\$ and \$t = 0^+\$. Since voltage can vary at any instant in a resistor, you would want to calculate current in the inductor at time t. Current in inductor at \$t= 0^+\$ is same as that of \$t = 0^-\$. The inductor would be a current source in the circuit after the switch is open at t>0. Use the current decay equation for the inductor to find current in it at time t>0.
When the switch is open, find the time constant of the circuit. This would be a parallel combination of all resistors and the inductor. R is the equivalent resistance as seen by the inductor L. Time constant \$τ = \frac {L}{R} \$.
Current in the inductor L at t>0 would be:
\$I(t) = I(0^+)e^{-\frac{t}{τ}} \$.
With this, you can calculate current in the 6kΩ resistor using mesh or nodal analysis as a function of t. v(t) is obtained by multiplying that current by 6k.

After performing the topological analysis with the node-voltages method of the electrical network and the effects on it with the switch closed and then opened, I determined the voltage transient at the terminals of R1 and L1. (In my previous study done by inspection, I found a Dirac impulse not actually present in the transient, I am modifying the analysis)

